# unable to remove slash after performing a replaceAll

Tags: java

```
Object jsonBody = getParsedJSONDocument(document);
Object href =  JsonPath.read(jsonBody, "$.href");

assertThat(href, is(String.format(System.getenv(ENDPOINT)+"%s", url).replaceAll("\\\\", "")));
```

I am trying to perform an assertion against a url and the issue I am having is the \ in the url when it gets it from the response.

It spits out `<["https:\/\/www.testenv\/examplesite.com\"]>`

How do I remove the slash and take it out of the array as I am expecting:

```
"https://www.testenv/examplesite.com"
```

Comment: And what was the input?

Comment: So I tired to include an example for confidentiality for the exact url, but bascially in the feature file it's examplesite.com. The ENDPOINT deals with https://www.testenv/ and then I am asserting against an api response for the url and even though the api through postman shows the correct url format, in the asserting when I try to receive it, it adds the special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the forward slashes were escaped in json: wrong data. If that is your statement.

```
String href = JsonPath.read(jsonBody, "$.href");
href = href.replace("\\", "");
```

Furthermore, though correct, better style would be simply using `+` or:

```
assertThat(href, is(String.format("%s%s", System.getenv(ENDPOINT), url)).replace("\\", ""));
```

Maybe you intended the replace to happen on href. In junit the *first* comparison element is the *expected* value, the second of the actual computed value.

Comment: Changing from object to string gives me error: java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (net.minidev.json.JSONArray is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: Ignore, put to object and then did a toString on the replace. Cool, it's getting somewhere, just the start and end of the url having the slashes